# Button click should save multiple html tables to csv with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, export-to-csv

I could partially solve this but I need help in retrieving the table. There is no database related to this.

I have two requests in my entire code, one is for POST and the second one is for DOWNLOAD. Below is the code for downloading into the csv file.

```
@app.route("/download")
def download_file():
    csv = '1,2,3\n4,5,6\n'
    return Response(
        csv,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                     "attachment; filename=Report.csv"})
```

This is working by the click of a button (results.html) , but it is providing me with a Report.csv with 123... which is mentioned in the csv variable.

**Button responsible for this function (results.html)**

```
<p>
    <a href="{{url_for('download_file')}}">Download</a>
</p>
```

**What I want to achieve:**

> Through the button click, the dynamic values within the html table
> should get saved as CSV.
>
> The html table has dynamic values. This html table is within
> results.html file.  These values are dependent on the images inputed
> by the user. The return statement (in the below code of POST request)
> provides values of what exactly the values are.

```
return render_template('uploads/results.html',
                                               msg='Processed successfully!',
                                               match=match,
                                               your_predicted_pattern_category=your_predicted_pattern_category,
                                               your_predicted_pattern_type=your_predicted_pattern_type,
                                               img_src=UPLOAD_INPUT_IMAGES_FOLDER + file.filename)
```

These are the values are in the html table which I want to also save if the user clicks on the above mentioned DOWNLOAD button

Comment: I am trying to understand here.  Do you want to trigger `@app.route("/download")` or `@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])` when you click button?

Comment: @Rahul I want to trigger this: @app.route("/download"). The button with the function is already created in the results.html. The results.html is "returned" in the post request which contains the table (thats why I posted the POST request too so that the return statement is visible)

Comment: If you put things step by step, you will have good chances of getting answer. I am intermediate flask dev but can not understand your question. I think you are mixing things up here. Please give minimum verifiable example. Remove unnecessary code. Once you get the answer, you can apply solution to your actual code.

Comment: I have just now reformatted my entire question for better understanding @Rahul

Answer (score -2):

Not sure but you might want to save the html table to a database and then retrieve the contents, save it to a folder and then export to csv

Comment: But I am storing it locally in the moment, its not related to the database at all. Like I mentioned, the html table is getting rendered fine, I just want to be able to store the values (return values in the POST request) into a csv.